# Facebook URL from chatbot user ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-chatbot

I have a fb messenger chatbot and the user ID I get from sender.id in fb's payload is different (app-scoped) than the user id that I can use to make a link to a user's profile page (for instance with: https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=[id] or shorter without the profile.php thingy).

Is there a way to get the "real" or "global" user profile facebook ID so that I could create a functioning link to a user's profile?

I've tried using app_scoped_user_id/[id] (as suggested in some existing answers) but it didn't work.

Comment: No. You can not get the real user ID from a page scoped user ID. If there was there would have been no reason to have page scoped user IDs

Answer (score 0):

Short answer No. It seems to be a design goal to limit all chatbot's access to user IDs to Page Scoped IDs. The designed way around this is to use the Account Linking approach facebook provides which will allow you to map from a PSID to your own system's credential. This still doesn't get you the user's FB ID but it does get you a global ID you can map to from other properties.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/account-linking